# Reading a product from JSON that may or may not have a size

Tags: python, json

How to do optimization and provide less of code here:

```
 for _ in _get_valid_json():
            if _['size'] != '':
                available_params = [
                    {'productSku': _['upcID']},
                    {'productUPC': _['upc']},
                    {'productColor': _['color']},
                    {'productSize': _['size']},
                    prod_price,
                    prod_name
                ]
            else:
                available_params = [
                    {'productSku': _['upcID']},
                    {'productUPC': _['upc']},
                    {'productColor': _['color']},
                    prod_price,
                    prod_name
                ]
```

I think it is not optimal way to use copy of same dict... maybe it can be done more dynamically?

Comment: Welcome on CodeReview.SE! Would you be able to tell us more about what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: @Josay I think it is not optimal way to use copy of same dict... maybe it can be done more dynamically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can append to a list after it has been created.

```
for _ in _get_valid_json():
    available_params = [
        {'productSku': _['upcID']},
        {'productUPC': _['upc']},
        {'productColor': _['color']}]

    if _['size'] != '':
        available_params.append({'productSize': _['size']})

    available_params.extend([prod_price, prod_name])
```

---

Taking a step back, this data structure looks like it will be a huge pain to work with. It is a list of key-value pairs where the ordering is significant (based on the fact that you wanted `productSize` at that specific location). So, not only do you need to know which value appears in which spot, you also have to know what the key name is to get the value. I don't know the use case here, but it seems like making an actual class would provide a much simpler interface to the user of the data.

Comment: To keep using `_` as anything other than an unused loop variable borders on *criminal*.

Comment: @codesparkle Agreed. I was focused on creating a better structure for the code and didn't mention that. I up voted jonrsharpe's answer that puts that point front and center.

Answer (score 6):

`_` is used in Python, by convention, to mean *"I'm not going to use this"*. For example:

```
random_nums = [random.randint(min_, max_) for _ in range(10)]
```

Here I'm creating a list of ten random numbers - I don't really need to use the index of each one, so I use the name `_` to let readers of my code (which, as always, includes future me!) know not to worry about that value.

In your code, by comparison, `_` is used for the variable that does everything. This is a terrible idea, given the convention above. Also, `_` is pretty low-profile visually, but here it's representing the most important thing.

I don't know exactly what your `_get_valid_json` returns, so I can't give a really useful variable name, but will use `d` instead.

---

It is not clear why `available_params` is a list containing single-element dictionaries and whatever `prod_price` and `prod_name` are (also single-element dictionaries?) Also, there is duplication - why not set up what you always need first, then add to it if needed?

I think the following would make more sense:

```
for d in _get_valid_json():
    available_params = {'productSku': d['upcID'], 'productUPC': d['upc'],
                        'productColor': d['color']}
    available_params.update(prod_price) # assuming single-element dictionary
    available_params.update(prod_name) # ditto
    if d['size']:
        available_params['productSize'] = d['size']
```

*Note that the empty string `''` evaluates `False` in a boolean context, so you don't need the explicit comparison.*

Now you can access the individual parameters much more easily (you don't need to go through the whole list looking for them) and if a function or method takes those parameters as arguments you can unpack the dictionary straight into it:

```
some_method(**available_params)
```